# gdb shows 1069 frames in backtrace

Tags: c++, gdb, backtrace

I'm looking at two different core files (one due to SEGV and the other due to ABRT).

Each of them has about 20 threads and when I do `thread apply all bt`, for about 5 threads in each core, it has 1069 lines as below.

```
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fc172ea8700 (LWP 20860)):
#0  0x00007fc178eb6f4d in unwind_stop () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000000013 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fc172ea7b50 in ?? ()
.
.
#1065 0x2e73757264656168 in ?? ()
#1066 0x656e6976646e6173 in ?? ()
#1067 0x04000f006d6f632e in ?? ()
#1068 0x0000000000000400 in ?? ()
#1069 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: That looks like you have stack problems. You probably write out of bounds of some local variable somewhere and the stack is messed up. Use a memory debugger tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, will do.

Comment: But is there any significance of the number 1069? I get the same number for lot of threads on multiple core files.

Comment: A corrupted stack is a corrupted stack, there's no meaning at all. Well, pehaps the meaning of the number is that *all* your threads corrupt their stack just the same way?

Comment: Another hint: infinite recursion leading to your SEGV and ABRT. But the addresses shown are very dirty (`0x0`, `0x400`, etc.). So it's very likely memory corruption leading to execution of arbitrary memory regions (by overwriting a return address for example).